# How to set credential for Google service account using JSON key added into application.yml in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-oauth, service-accounts

I am doing in google api service using google service account. I have this problem how to set value for builder to credential this api. How to set it in JSON key

```
    public GoogleCredential googleCredential() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        Collection<String> scope = new ArrayList<String>();
        scope.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        Builder credentialBuilder = new Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory);
       
        return new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId("xxx")
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scope)
            )
            .build();
    }
```

I want to create application.yml to store this JSON key like this:

```
google-drive:
  type: "service_account",
  project_id: "xx-387809",
  private_key_id: "xxxxxxx",
  private_key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxxx-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  client_email: "xxxxx-387809.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  client_id: "00000000",
  auth_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  token_uri: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  auth_provider_x509_cert_url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  client_x509_cert_url: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxxxx-387809.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  universe_domain: "googleapis.com"
```

to run my service with this config

Comment: Why did you download the p12 file. you should use one or the other not both.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo this is in my example code. I want to use json key not p12 key

Comment: Then I don't understand the issue why "I am using p12 key file"

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo sorry my bad at English. I already edited

Comment: Okay i get it.   Check below let me know if you have any issues and i will test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the JSON key as a String application property for example on the `application.yml`

```
  google:
     privateKey:
       json: '{"type":"service_account","project_id":"mocked-project","private_key_id":"mocked_private_key","private_key":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxxx-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n","client_email":"mocked-service-account@mocked-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com","client_id":"123577123897123","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/mock-service-account%40mocked-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"}'
```

Then you can parse the credentials with the `fromStream()` method `GoogleCredentials`, for example:

```java
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(privateKeyJson.getBytes());
GoogleCredential cr = GoogleCredential.fromStream(in);
```

Finally, after obtaining the credentials you can use the `GoogleCredentials.Builder()` to set the service account properties

Here is an example:

```java
    GoogleCredential cr = GoogleCredential.fromStream(in);
    return new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jacksonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountId(cr.getServiceAccountId())
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(cr.getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyId(cr.getServiceAccountPrivateKeyId())
        .setTokenServerEncodedUrl(cr.getTokenServerEncodedUrl())
        .setServiceAccountId("xxx")
        .setServiceAccountScopes(scope)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
public class DriveWithServiceAccountQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "your awesome app";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/path/to/your/service-account-key-downloaded-from-google-api-console.json";

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH))
                .createScoped(SCOPES));
        Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, requestInitializer)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
        FileList result = driveService.files().list()
                .setPageSize(10)
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                .execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
        if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No files found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Files:");
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/path/to/your/service-account-key-downloaded-from-google-api-console.json"`. So I must create a key file store in my server and read this JSON key file to credential. Is there anyway to add it into my configure spring boot application.yml. Like configure I write above.

Comment: There should be but tbh im a little rusty with java it loads it as fromStream so if you can covert it to a memory stream it should work.   there may be another method on ServiceAccountCredentials that allows loading from an object i cant recall.